# Printing check mark is triggering warning when running R cmd checks

Tags: r, printing, package, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I‘m writing a simple function that reads multiple files from the user, then it prints into the terminal (`print`) file name and yes or no next to it, if it was valid/invalid. I would like to use `x/✓`symbols.

The problem however, since the check symbol is not in ascii, R cmd is throwing a warning. I tried several approaches (`charToRaw, intToUtf8, symbol(“\326”)` yet non is working with simple print in terminal.
As an example:

```
Df <- data.frame(file = myfiles, status = “x”)
Df$status[1]= “✓”
print (Df)
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cli` package offers a way to print these with `cli_alert_success` and `cli_alert_danger`. Presumably, you have some more complicated check as to if the file was valid. Store that as a boolean instead of the explicit character.

```
Df <- data.frame(file = myfiles, isValid = myValidityCheckFx(myfiles))
purrr::walk2(
    Df$file, Df$isValid, 
    ~if(.y) cli::cli_alert_success(.x) else cli::cli_alert_danger(.x)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works; I'm wondering if there is also a way to show something similar to `devtools::check()` or `devtools::test()`, or is it just the formatting? thanks again

Comment: `devtools` uses various functions from `cli` to output messages.  Those two functions include calls to other packages including `rmdcheck` and `testthat`, which also use `cli`

Comment: If you want you can dig into the source code to see how `cli` does it: https://github.com/r-lib/cli/tree/main/R